# https to http htaccess redirect not working when SSL enabled

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect

I'm trying to redirect http to https on all pages via an htaccess in the main root of the website (shared hosting). I can't understand why this isn't working? This is the entire content of the htaccess file. Whilst there seem to be similar questions already asked on Stackoverflow, I can't find any solutions that would seem to be of help.

There is one folder/directory on the website that requires SSL so I can't disable SSL on the whole website. That folder has its own htaccess file.

The second chunk of code is very standard as it's a Joomla website. I can't imagine the issue would be in there?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

##### Joomla! core SEF Section -- BEGIN
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw|ini|zip|json|file|vcf))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
##### Joomla! core SEF Section -- END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use joomla first disable ssl, than use above code because I have use this code also and its working.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: There is one folder/directory on the website that requires SSL so I can't disable SSL on the whole website. That folder has its own htaccess file.